# Xamarin iOS App check if GPS is enabled or prompt the user

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, gps

Hi I am looking into an app which is written in Xamarin iOS.  The feature I am trying to implement is

GPS must be enabled when app is running, if gps is not enabled prompt the user to enable. If the answer is yes enable the gps and continue otherwise exit app.

I am really new Xamarin and mobile development in general.  After research i have found this link which shows the lifecycle of Xamarin iOS app.

[Xamarin Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo)

The question I have is

1) Will I be able to show an alert to user from App Delegate to enable GPS when app returns from background or launched in the overrides (See link)

2) If a dialog is not possible from app delegate will it be better to create a new screen and show the dialog to enable gps instead of adding gps check in all screens.

3) Is this the correct way of checking if GPS is enabled

e.g., when app returns from background

```
 public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App will enter foreground");
            if(CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, you can show a alert to user, and this way is correct .And if you set GPS enabled, the system default alert will show in app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @Abe you are on the right path!

1. Yes, you will be. You just have to place it in the overrides as you mentioned.
2. You can place the check in the AppDelegate, but it may not be the best thing to do. You might want to just place it in the Appear override of your page.
3. Yes using AppDelegate lifecycle overrides, is one way of checking for GPS if you need the it when your app is in the background.

Tips:

1. If you are using Xamarin Native, inside the ViewController, you could instead use the ViewDidLoad override to perform the check for GPS
2. You could instead just also just look into the [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=ios) examples for a simplified way of dealing with GPS